# Rails count and group by two attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

following model constellation:

```rb
class Attempt < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :question
end
```

```rb
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
end
```

```rb
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :answers
  has_many :attempts
end
```

A Question has several Answers, where one is marked as correct (column `correct`). The user attempts to guess the right answer to a question.

**Challenge**: I want to know for a user for each question, how many attempts were a success (correct answer chosen) and how many a failure, without firing several / many queries against the database.

What brought me closest to a satisfying answer was `Question.joins(attempts: [:answer]).group('(attempts.question_id, answers.correct)').count` (ignoring the there user so far). Resulting SQL:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, (attempts.question_id, answers.correct) AS attempts_question_id_answers_correct FROM "questions" INNER JOIN "attempts" ON "attempts"."question_id" = "questions"."id" INNER JOIN "answers" ON "answers"."id" = "attempts"."answer_id" GROUP BY (attempts.question_id, answers.correct)
```

The values are correct, but the result looks pretty strange with these "(1,f) etc." keys:

```
{"(1,f)"=>4, "(3,t)"=>2, "(2,t)"=>4, "(2,f)"=>11, "(3,f)"=>6, "(1,t)"=>4}
```

I'd appreciate any help especially on the result set :) . Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: For the moment I just took it as it is, changed the _query_ to `Question.joins(attempts: [:answer]).group(['attempts.question_id', 'answers.correct']).count` and got `{[1, false]=>4, [3, true]=>2, [2, true]=>4, [2, false]=>11, [3, false]=>6, [1, true]=>4}` out it. Not perfect, but something to work with. Cooler solutions still requested ;) ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
Question.joins(attempts: [:answer]).select("attempts.question_id as question_id, answers.correct as correct_answer").group('(attempts.question_id, answers.correct)').count
```